# Multi-module Zend Application

Tags: php, zend-framework

I having a problem with a Zend Multi Module Application which is:

```
An error occurred
Page not found
Exception information:
Message: Invalid controller specified (JorgeFerrari)
Stack trace:

#0 C:\Arquivos de programas\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 C:\Arquivos de programas\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 C:\Arquivos de programas\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#3 C:\Arquivos de programas\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\JorgeFerrari\public\index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#4 {main}  
Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'JorgeFerrari',
  'action' => 'public',
  'module' => 'default',
)
```

I have this in my Application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules = ""
```

And 3 modules: default, panel, client

All of then with their own Bootstrap: (Default_Bootstrap, Panel_Bootstrap, Client_Bootstrap)

And all of then with an Index_Controller: (IndexController, Panel_IndexController, Client_IndexController)

All the folder structure are right (i guess...)

Anything i can do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance, Jorge.

**EDIT**

Back to the old problem listed above...

Comment: Can you provide more info like how you defined this controller and what url you are trying to access (taking in consideration camel case)

Comment: Just trying to access the index =(

Comment: For the second error, may need to name the bootstrap Default_Bootstrap? I'm assuming you have a Bootstrap class at application/Bootstrap.php

Comment: As for the the initial question, I had a similar issue. It had to do with my ACL configuration. Not sure if you're using ACL, which is why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: Yes i do use ACL, i'll try to rename all the default stuff to Default_, brb.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Resource matching "view" not found... it din't work. Getting pretty sad about this stuff :(

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you stated in your array to look for a controller named `JorgeFerrari`.

But you say you only have the following controllers: (IndexController, Panel_IndexController, Client_IndexController)

Comment: Cool. Glad you solved your problem. What was the issue? I'm just curious since I've been dealing with various ZF issues on one of my projects.